# Does Jena support SPARQL 1.1 entailment regimes?

Tags: sparql, jena, reasoning

First of all, *Jena* has its own *reasoner* and even together with *Pellet* and *RDF serialization*, we can inference over RDF graph using *SPARQL*. I am wondering what is the role of *SPARQL entailment regimes* here? How does Jena support the *SPARQL entailment regimes*?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Jena has an architecture for supporting SPARQL entailment regimes - a regime can provide its own solutions basic graph pattern matching. Jena does not (currently) provide any of the specific entailment regimes described in the spec.  It provides simple entailment (the matching of BGPs that is in the query language spec) and other forms via inference graphs.

The role of the SPARQL entailment regimes is to formalise a way in which entailment is combined with SPARQL as well as certain specific regimes.